# mysqldump with binary data files

Tags: linux, mysql

How to backup the mysql binary files?

When executing this in the command line it prompts for a password even if its mentioned in the syntax.. After typing in the password an error is returned saying that the database (the password) is unkown.. password and database is swapped in the syntax???

syntax

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u USER -p PASSWORD DB | gzip > /var/mysql_backup.gz
```

error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'PASSWORD' when selecting the database
```

## edit

```
exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u USER -pPASS DB | gzip > /var/mysql_backup.gz', $rtn, $err);

        echo 'rtn = ';
        print_r($rtn);
        echo 'err = ';
        print_r($err);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without a space after `-p`:

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u USER -pPASSWORD DB | gzip > /var/mysql_backup.gz
```

Comment: thanks.. but how do you then restore an ealier backup file? :)

Comment: @clarkk `mysql -uroot -p < earlier_backup.sql`

Comment: @clarkk Or if still gzipped:  `zcat earlier_backup.gz` |mysql -uroot -p`

Comment: hmm.. but isn't it possible to run the syntax from PHP? Do PHP need permission?! Question edited..

Comment: @clarkk The whole zcat command can be run via `exec()` in PHP. You might need to specify the full path to `zcat` though.

Comment: @clarkk Apache in PHP would need permission to write to /var/mysql_backup.gz. That is probably where it fails. Write to a directory owned or writable by the web server user.